Postgres 15 column drop impact
Is the drop column operation scalable?
Previously, we faced issues while updating a large number of records because it took more space.
Is this the case with a drop column operation?

You may find this useful?

ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN ... is a very fast operation, because it only changes the metadata and does not rewrite the table.
There are two things you should be aware of:

Dropping a column does not reduce the size of the table, since the existing rows are not modified. New table rows will be missing the dropped column. VACUUM (FULL) won't help, you'd have to update the table.

ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN ... requires a brief ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on the table, which conflicts with all other access, even with queries.



We are considering passing a bulk update because the dropped column is large (toast). Is there some RAM used by dropped columns when reading a row with such a metadata change? Or maybe reads/wrire are faster after a bulk update? We do not care about disk.

The columns are still there for existing rows, so they will affect reading speed, and they are also cached in RAM. Writes won't be affected. Note that if the column is really large, it might be toasted out of line, and a VACUUM (FULL) of the toast table would do the trick.
